# Error .format is not a function javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey i am creating this clock in javascript as i have written my code but there is an error which say {00}+{00}+{00}.format is not a function

```
class Counter
{
 constructer(Name)
{
    this.count = 0;
    this.name = Name;   
}

get Value(){
    return this.count;
}

get Name(){
    return this.name;   
}


set Name(value){
    this.name = value;  
}
Increment()
{
    this.count++;   
}
Reset()
{
    this.count = 0;
}


}
```

This is My clock Class IN which there is a time method which have that format thing, if anyone can help me, basically i am printing hour mintues and seconds in the 00 00 00 format

```
class clock
{

constructer()
{
    this._hour = new Counter("hour");
    this._minutes = new Counter("Minutes");
    thi._seconds = new Counter("Seconds");
}

["Time"](){

    var time = '{"00"} + {"00"} + {"00"}'.format(this._hour, this._minutes, this._seconds);
}   

["Reset"]()
{
    this._hour.Reset();
    this._minutes.Reset();
    this._seconds.Reset();
}   

["Tick"]()
{
    this._seconds.Increment();
    if(_seconds.Value == 60)
    {
        _minutes.Increment();
        _seconds.Reset();
    }
    if(_minutes.Value == 60)
    {
        _hour.Increment();
        _minutes.Reset();
        _seconds.Reset();
    }   
    if(_hour == 24)
    {
        Reset();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well, [strings don't have a `format` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods). What made you think they do? Also, `["Tick"]()`, etc, can just be written as `Tick()`.

Comment: javascript strings do not have a format property - you're thinking of some made up language

Comment: Instead of `["Time"](){`…`}` you can also simply use `"Time"(){`…`}` or `Time(){`…`}`.

Comment: Also, `constructer` is not a constructor.

Comment: `this._seconds.Increment();` ... then you `if(_seconds.Value == 60)` without `this.` ... seems like you've randomly smashed your hands on they keyboard and expected javascript to ["know what you meant"](https://jsfiddle.net/1facL01m/)

Comment: then how i will convert my numbers into string

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate your numbers as strings. The following code will print the string `9:11:56`:

```
hours = 9
minutes = 11
seconds = 56

console.log(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds)
```

Here's a [link](https://repl.it/Mzd9) to the same code on REPL.it.